# KeyPress and Keydown is not working on this particular code.only key up is working

Tags: javascript

the code should only allow numbers and  not allow the special characters and symbols and charcters in the textbox.but the keypress and keydown function are not working in this code.here it also stops the numbers from entering into the textbox.

```
function radioValidation() {
    var x = document.exform.tags;
    var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
    var namepattern = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
    var letters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z-]+$/;
    var radioId = $('input:checked').val();
    if (radioId == "mobileno") {
        x.maxLength = "11";
        if (!numbers.test(x.value)) {
            x.value = "";
            document.getElementById('chose').innerHTML = "Numbers only";
            x.focus();
            return false;
        }
        document.getElementById('chose').innerHTML = "";
    } else if (radioId == "firstname") {
        x.maxLength = "50";
        if (!namepattern.test(x.value)) {
            x.value = "";
            document.getElementById('chose').innerHTML = "Enter only               alphabets.";
            x.focus();
            return false;
        }
        document.getElementById('chose').innerHTML = "";
    } else {
        x.maxLength = "15";
        if (!letters.test(x.value)) {
            x.value = "";
            document.getElementById('chose').innerHTML = "No specail charecters";
            x.focus();
            return false;
        }
        document.getElementById('chose').innerHTML = "";
    }
    return true;
}


<input type="text" name="tags" id="tags" size="35px;"
                                class="form-control" onkeypress="return radioValidation()">
<label id="chose" style="color: red; width: 150px;"></label>
```

Comment: This is JavaScript not Java. Please detag Java from this question. Those two languages are very different

Answer (score 0):

If you want numbers only.

```
function numbersOnly(params){
    return params && !isNaN(params) ? true:false;
}
```

and since your using jquery you can actually

```
$(".form-control").on("keyup",function(){
    var whatyouwilldo = numbersOnly($('input:checked').val());
}
```

You can play with whatyouwilldo variable :)

Comment: sorry the above code does not match my requirement .anyways thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `onkeyup()` instead of `keypress()`

Html

```
<input type="text" name="tags" id="tags" size="35px;"
                                class="form-control" onkeyup="return radioValidation()">
<label id="chose" style="color: red; width: 150px;"></label>
```

Javascript

```
function radioValidation() {

    var x = document.getElementById("tags");    

    var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
    var namepattern = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
    var letters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z-]+$/;

        if (!numbers.test(x.value)) {
            x.value = "";
            document.getElementById('chose').innerHTML = "Numbers only";
            x.focus();
            return false;
        }

    return true;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xwhejrm8/)

Comment: the problem with the onkeyup is if we use it is allowing characters and special charcters when when the key is up it disappears.my requirement i should not allow the charcters to be entered